# How to integrate an expandable Floating Action Button

Tags: java, android

I am a beginner in android development using Java,
I have tried surfing the net but to no avail.
What is name of the library which I can use to make expandable Floating Action Button like the one on the pic below.
Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking at some source codes. I found a best expandable FAB(Float Action Button)

Let me add those source codes.
Add it to build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.nambimobile.widgets:expandable-fab:1.0.2'
```

Add following source code to layout

```
<!-- This is NOT a root view, but should be a child of whatever root view you 

choose (CoordinatorLayout, ConstraintLayout, etc) -->
<com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.ExpandableFabLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
  
  <!-- The next 3 Views will only display in portrait orientation -->          
  <com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.Overlay
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:overlay_orientation="portrait"/>
  <com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.ExpandableFab
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ui_margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/ui_margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ui_margin_medium"
    app:efab_orientation="portrait"/>
  <com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.FabOption
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fab_orientation="portrait"
    app:label_text="Portrait Option 1"
    android:onClick="onClickPortraitOption1"/>

  <!-- The next 3 Views will only display in landscape orientation -->
  <com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.Overlay
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:overlay_orientation="landscape"/>
  <com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.ExpandableFab
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/ui_margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/ui_margin_medium"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/ui_margin_medium"
    app:efab_orientation="landscape"/>
  <com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.FabOption
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fab_orientation="landscape"
    app:label_text="Landscape Option 1"
    android:onClick="onClickLandscapeOption1"/>
            
</com.nambimobile.widgets.efab.ExpandableFabLayout>
```

Then, you can use those FAB as you use on button in Java file.

Let me add that [link](https://github.com/nambicompany/expandable-fab)

Comment: @Terre If it is correct answer for you. Than, you can mark it as correct answer. So, others could find the answer easily